# Why is my string property (in my core data model) limited to 50 characters?

Tags: cocoa

I have a core data model with a variety of properties. For some reason the string properties are limited to 50 characters even though no max value (or default value for that matter) is set.

Interesting thing is that it was fine before I added fetch requests using the browser view of the data model.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: what language? please tag it with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you validating that the length is 50?

if you print the object in gdb, you'll only see the first 50 by default.

from what I've observed, the debugDescription method for an NSManagedObject prints out 50 or 51 characters when you po managedObjectInstance

I've found that in in gdb, do a po [managedObject valueForKey:@"attribName"] will return the whole string.

Not sure if the fetch request has anything to do with it.